# Automatically add github issues using a keyword in source code

Tags: github

Does anyone know if there's a way to add a github issue automatically when a keyword appears in a commit (source code)? 
I usually put a `TODO` comment in to mark somewhere that needs work, and thought it would be really useful to track them using issues

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming. [Why we're not customer support for your favorite company](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/369450)

Comment: @cpburnz I don't see what's wrong in a question looking for a useful library/extension. I'm trying to see if this feature exists before I implement it myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible.
All you can do in commit messages is [close](https://help.github.com/articles/closing-issues-via-commit-messages/) or references issues.
Not create one.

Comment: I don't mean in commit message but rather the source code to commit

Comment: Neither of those allows it.